# QTableWidget filled with QLineEdits does not fire signals

Tags: c++, qt, signals

I'm relatively new to QT. In my code, I create a QTableWidget, iterate through the rows and set the cells to QLineEdits and QCheckBoxes. I want to make it so that changing the text within any of the QLineEdits or checking/unchecking the QCheckBoxes causes my table to fire a signal passing either the item in question, or the row/column that it's within.

I build the table here:

```
for(int row=0; row < conditionTable->rowCount(); row++)
{
    QLineEdit *condition = new QLineEdit;
    conditionTable->setCellWidget(row, 0, condition);

    QLineEdit *minBoundField = new QLineEdit;
    conditionTable->setCellWidget(row, 1, minBoundField);

    QLineEdit *maxBoundField = new QLineEdit;
    conditionTable->setCellWidget(row, 2, maxBoundField);

    QCheckBox *checkbox = new QCheckBox;
    conditionTable->setCellWidget(row, 3, checkbox);

    if(row > 0)
    {
        condition->setReadOnly(true);
        minBoundField->setReadOnly(true);
        maxBoundField->setReadOnly(true);
        checkbox->setCheckable(false);
    }
}
```

I then try to make it so that changes to the table can be handled by one of the slot methods:

```
connect(conditionTable, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QTableWidgetItem*)),
        this, SLOT(handleConditionTableChange(QTableWidgetItem*)));
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, and I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using QLineEdit and QCheckBox here.

To add a check box to your QTableWidget do the following:

```
QTableWidgetItem* item =  new QTableWidgetItem("check box");
item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
tableWidget->setItem(row, column, item);
```

To add an line edit:

```
QTableWidgetItem* item =  new QTableWidgetItem("line edit");
tableWidget->setItem(row, column, item);
```

With this setup, the signal will be emitted when an item is changed.

Edit:
For your example, try something like:

```
for(int row=0; row < conditionTable->rowCount(); row++)
{
    QTableWidgetItem* condition =  new QTableWidgetItem("");
    conditionTable->setItem(row, 0, condition);

    QTableWidgetItem *minBoundField = new QTableWidgetItem("");
    conditionTable->setItem(row, 1, minBoundField);

    QTableWidgetItem *maxBoundField = new QTableWidgetItem("");
    conditionTable->setItem(row, 2, maxBoundField);

    QTableWidgetItem *checkbox = new QTableWidgetItem("");
    checkbox->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable);
    checkbox->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked);
    conditionTable->setItem(row, 3, checkbox);

    if(row > 0)
    {
        condition->setFlags(Qt::NoItemFlags);
        minBoundField->setFlags(Qt::NoItemFlags);
        maxBoundField->setFlags(Qt::NoItemFlags);
        checkbox->setFlags(Qt::NoItemFlags);
    }
}
```

If you still want to use QLineEdit and QCheckBox for some reason, you will need to connect each line edit and each check box to a slot.

Comment: I tried that out. What it does is create a table filled with cells that say "line edit" and "check box".

Comment: That's a lot closer, thanks. The only problem is that I'm not able to edit any of the cells even with the Qt::ItemIsEditable line. (Also, in your example, item->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked) should be checkbox->setCheckState(Qt::Unchecked), but this is trivial)

Comment: Awesome! I OR'd the flags you specify with the flags it already has (e.g. condition->flags | Qt::ItemIsEditable), which makes the cells editable and allows me to successfully make my program crash on my ItemChanged handler method. :) Meaning this issue's resolved, cheers.