# Emit signal on editing data in a QTableWidget cell

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qt-signals

I am searching for a signal that is emitted on editing a cell in a QTableWidget. I don't want "cellChanged" because it is just emitted on lefting the cell.

Example:
When I input "abc" into a cell, I want a signal after "a", after "b" and after "c". In this case, I want the signal three times. "cellChanged" emits the signal only one time after lefting the cell.

Is there a possibility to realize this?

Comment: What are the widgets in your QTableWidget? It seems that they are QLineEdits, so you have to use the cells' widgets signals, not the QTableWidget one

Comment: I have an emty tabel that is createt with this code (in python3/pyqt5):

tablewid = QTableWidget(1,5)

Or shall I add ItemDelegate (QLineEdit) and use the "textEdited"-signal?

Comment: Yes, you could try that, even if it's not a so clear solution or maybe try following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20033691/qtablewidget-filled-with-qlineedits-does-not-fire-signals

Comment: Thank you to Andre and quazeeee

I did it in this way:

    table = QTableWidget(1,5)
    le = QLineEdit()
    table.setCellWidget(0, 0, le)
    le.textEdited.connect(myfunction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need use keyPressEvent signal. In this event you can emit you own signal in proper case